# Can't compile test DAML module

Tags: daml

I am trying to compile a DAML module similar to how it's done in the [Digital Asset quickstart guide](https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/quickstart.html).

When I run

```
da run damlc -- package daml/Main.daml target/daml/test_project2
```

in my project directory (which was created by typing `da new test_project2`) I get the following error

```
da-hs-damlc-app: target/daml/test_project2.dar: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I don't understand, isn't this command supposed to be creating the file called `target/daml/test_project2.dar`? What is my project missing?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that the SDK installation didn't fully succeed and the DAML compiler is not present. The easiest way to fix that would be to switch back and forth between SDK versions to trigger the SDK Assistant to retry downloading the package. Try running `da use 0.11.2`, `da upgrade` and `da use 0.11.3` in that sequence. Note that depending on which SDK version you are on right now (check via `da list`), you may have to change the SDK version in the project's `da.yaml` file to `0.11.3` as well.

Comment: Thank You! I had recently updgraded to 0.11.3 but the da.yaml still showed 0.10.9.  Now it complies!